# How can I change colours in Outlook via VSTO?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

Good Morning,
Since a few days, I'm searching for an opportunity to change colours in Outlook by VSTO (Visual Studio Tools for Office - C#).
I would like to change the colour of the recipient, which I write down when I would like to send an e-mail.
Is that even possible?

I don't find anything on the web about that, but it would be the best solution for my project.

Comment: Where exactly do you need to change colors? Could you post a screenshot with a highlighted area?

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook extensibility model doesn't provide anything for customizing the Outlook UI, i.e. changing colors of the recipients.

The best what you could do is to use the [ContactItem.Categories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.contactitem.categories) property which allows setting a string representing the categories assigned to the Outlook item.

Categories is a delimited string of category names that have been assigned to an Outlook item. This property uses the character specified in the value name, `sList`, under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International` in the Windows registry, as the delimiter for multiple categories.